# How can I use block syntax with Minitest?

Tags: ruby, testing, rubygems, minitest

In Rails we can use Minitest with this syntax:

```
test "true" do
  assert true
end
```

When I try using this syntax in my gem I get an `ArgumentError` (wrong number of arguments).

To be clear, I don't care for the rspec syntax (I prefer `assert` over `describe` blocks). I only want to write `test "foo" do` instead of `def test_foo`.

How can I do this?

My `test_helper.rb` is almost empty:

```
gem 'minitest'
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'foo/bar'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an ActiveSupport thing as far as I know, not a Minitest thing

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/declarative.rb

A quick thing you could do is require 'minitest/spec' and alias `it` as `test`